# Using Custom Dlls in Azure Function Visual Studio Preview

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core, azure-functions

How do you import a custom class library into an Azure Function in Visual Studio? I have currently built the class library and added it to the bin folder in the Azure Function project. I added the reference to the class in the run.csx.

run.csx:

```
#r "../bin/ClassLibrary1.dll"

using System;
using ClassLibrary1;

public static void Run(TimerInfo myTimer, TraceWriter log)
{
     log.Info($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");
     dynamic class1 = new Class1();
}
```

This throws an error after the function sets up the timer stating its missing System.Runtime. I've attempted to add System.Runtime but have had no luck. The class library is .net core, but I will also be referencing a .net 4.6 class library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dakota,

Dependencies would usually be deployed/referenced with a .NET Core application or library, typically by referencing the appropriate NuGet packages. So you'll need to either reference the required packages or copy your assembly's dependencies into the same folder.

Also, it seems like it was the case, but please make sure your .NET Core library targets, at most, Netstandard 1.3.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Added the reference as you stated and checked my NetStandard is 1.6
This is the error im currently receiving:
A ScriptHost error has occurred
Exception while executing function: Functions.TimerTriggerCSharp. mscorlib: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. f-TimerTriggerCSharp__1128197424: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: You'll need to either ensure the dependencies (dlls) are deployed with your library your that you add a package reference to `System.Runtime`(https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Runtime/), but those dependencies need to be brought in (that's the nature of .NET Core apps) as they're not part of the framework.
I'll update the answer to remove the built in assembly reference as that is indeed not applicable in this particular case.
Also, you'll need to target Netstandard 1.3 or below when running on functions. Fixing that above as well it wasn't clear.

Comment: Im marking this as the answer. If anyone else has this issue it turns out that you need to reinstall Visual Studios and make sure to remove references to previous versions. Visual studio had a corrupt devenv and other issues. After installing a fresh copy it worked perfect and like Fabio stated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Similar issue here referencing my custom class library from a C# function, initial error was:

"The type 'Attribute' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51"

The issue was that I was targeting NetStandard 2.0 in my project (by default), and once I downgraded to 1.3 it worked.